# What happened to this tomato?

Tags: identification, tomatoes

It's Cherry Roma, and every time they turn red this happens. Is it because of the sun? They are in an area where there is more direct sunlight. Is this also safe to eat?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

likely heavy watering after it was ripe. At some point in maturity the skin loses most of its flexibility and if the fruit expands with good water supply it can split the skin. I would say eat it or cook it as soon as possible because various molds, etc. can have access at the split skin.